# Org Charts: Childrens not shown on specific scenarios

Tags: javascript

I am using Org Charts plugin.
showChildren() method not showing all children.

```
  var $rsContainer = $('#reportingStructure');

  var reportingConfig = $('#reportingStructure').orgchart({
    'data' : reportingData,
    'nodeId': 'id',
    'nodeContent': 'title',
    'nodeTemplate': nodeTemplate,
    'direction': 'l2r',
    'visibleLevel':1
  });

  var nodeTemplate = function(data) {
    return `<div>
                <div class="title">${data.name}</div>
                <div class="content">${data.title}</div>
            </div>`;
  };

  $rsContainer.on('click', '.node', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#selected-node').val($this.find('.title').text()).data('node', $this);
    var $node = $('#selected-node').data('node');
    var childNodeStatus = reportingConfig.getNodeState($node, 'children')
    var siblingNodesStatus = reportingConfig.getNodeState($node, 'siblings')
    console.log(childNodeStatus);
    console.log(siblingNodesStatus);

    if (childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && !siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.showChildren($node)
    } else if(childNodeStatus.exist && childNodeStatus.visible && !siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.hideChildren($node)
    } else if(childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.showChildren($node)
      reportingConfig.hideSiblings($node)
    } else if(childNodeStatus.exist && childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.hideChildren($node)
      reportingConfig.showSiblings($node)
    } else if(childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.showChildren($node)
      reportingConfig.hideSiblings($node)
    }

  });
```

[Check this example](https://codepen.io/dannykoshy/pen/eMqKwx)

Scenario

Click 1 > 2B > 3B
Then click 2B
Again click 2B (Only 3B is shown, 3A is not shown)
It calls showChildren() but childrens are not shown. 3A still seems to have hidden class to it

[This is the plugin documentation](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know orgcharts library, but I found a solution. The problem I saw is that nodes hidden with `.hideSiblings($node)` are not shown when `.showChildren($node)` is executed on their parent node.

The changes that fix it are listed below. I think this is a generic solution but I didn't check every combination.

I replaced every:

```
reportingConfig.showChildren($node)
```

with:

```
showChildren($node);
```

And the `showChildren()` function is:

```
  function showChildren($node) {
    reportingConfig.showChildren($node);
    var children = reportingConfig.getRelatedNodes($node, 'children');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      reportingConfig.showSiblings($(children[i]));
    }
  }
```

See snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var reportingData = {
    'name': '1',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'children': [{
        'name': '2A',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'name': '2B',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
            'name': '3A',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
          },{
            'name': '3C',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
          },
          {
            'name': '3B',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [{
                'name': '4A',
                'title': 'engineer'
              },
              {
                'name': '4B',
                'title': 'UE engineer',
                'children': [{
                    'name': '5A',
                    'title': 'engineer'
                  },
                  {
                    'name': '5B',
                    'title': 'UE engineer'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': '2C',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'name': '2D',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'name': '2E',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
            'name': '3A',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
          },
          {
            'name': '3B',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [{
                'name': '4A',
                'title': 'engineer'
              },
              {
                'name': '4B',
                'title': 'UE engineer'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': '2F',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'name': '2G',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'name': '2H',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }
    ]
  };

  var $rsContainer = $('#reportingStructure');

  var reportingConfig = $('#reportingStructure').orgchart({
    'data': reportingData,
    'nodeId': 'id',
    'nodeContent': 'title',
    'nodeTemplate': nodeTemplate,
    'direction': 'l2r',
    'visibleLevel': 1
  });

  var nodeTemplate = function(data) {
    return `<div>
                    <div class="title">${data.name}</div>
                    <div class="content">${data.title}</div>
                </div>`;
  };

  $rsContainer.on('click', '.node', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#selected-node').val($this.find('.title').text()).data('node', $this);
    var $node = $('#selected-node').data('node');
    var childNodeStatus = reportingConfig.getNodeState($node, 'children')
    var siblingNodesStatus = reportingConfig.getNodeState($node, 'siblings')
    //console.log(childNodeStatus);
    //console.log(siblingNodesStatus);
    //debugger;

    if (childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && !siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      showChildren($node);
    } else if (childNodeStatus.exist && childNodeStatus.visible && !siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.hideChildren($node)
    } else if (childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      showChildren($node);
      reportingConfig.hideSiblings($node)
    } else if (childNodeStatus.exist && childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      reportingConfig.hideChildren($node)
      reportingConfig.showSiblings($node)
    } else if (childNodeStatus.exist && !childNodeStatus.visible && siblingNodesStatus.exist && !siblingNodesStatus.visible) {
      showChildren($node);
      reportingConfig.hideSiblings($node)
    }

  });

  function showChildren($node) {
 reportingConfig.showChildren($node);
 var children = reportingConfig.getRelatedNodes($node, 'children');
 for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   reportingConfig.showSiblings($(children[i]));
 }
  }
})
```

```css
.orgchart .edge {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.1/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.1/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="selected-node" />
<div id="reportingStructure"></div>
```

Comment: That's a nice catch. But yes it solves only this sequence. if you go deeper inside children and click grandparents it doesn't solve the problem. Ex: 1 > 2B > 3B > 4B > 2B, then the deeper levels will have issues.

Comment: @DannyKoshy I think you need to check every `if-else` block and tweak them to execute `showSiblings()` on every `$node` which has siblings which has been hidden with `hideChildren()`. Also it's possible we're missing a more fundamental concept... as I said, I really don't know the library :(

Comment: @DannyKoshy Take a look at this other solution: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/hyanagor/

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Good catch. Thanks mate!

Comment: There is a bug in the updated code you did. please do the same flow in this https://jsfiddle.net/dmy3m1ng/

Comment: @DannyKoshy I did  1 > 2B > 3B > 4B > 2B and it looks right for me. 2B's children are not shown because of your original implementation which I tried to preserve. I mean: in both versions (yours and mine), if you click on a visible node, it collapses. So when I click 2B at the end of the sequence, 2B childrens are hidden.

Comment: Check 1 > 2B > 3B > 2B > 2B you will find the bug

Comment: Also fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/xuo6xgy6/ (code snippet updated too)